# Stable geodesics

Tags: riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, geodesic

Consider a function defined on some space of smooth curves in a manifold (think of the "action functional"). I understand what a "critical point" of such a function is, but what is understood by a *stable* critical point? In particular, what is a *stable* geodesic?